# Remove NA's when adding in R

Tags: r, addition, na

I'm trying to add two matrices in R, and I'd like the addition to treat any NA's as 0's.  I know I could always do something like this:

```
ifelse(is.na(A), 0, A) + ifelse(is.na(B), 0, B)
```

but it seems like there should be a more elegant way of doing this.  For example, is there some way of supplying the na.rm argument to the + function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that "A" and "B" have the same dimensions,

```
`dim<-`(colSums(rbind(c(A), c(B)), na.rm=TRUE), dim(A))
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    4    7    6    6
 #[2,]    5    7    2    4
 #[3,]    8    9    6    1
 #[4,]    4    2    5    5
```

Or instead of `ifelse`, we could use `replace` which will be a bit faster

```
  replace(A, is.na(A), 0) +replace(B, is.na(B), 0)
  #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  #[1,]    4    7    6    6
  #[2,]    5    7    2    4
  #[3,]    8    9    6    1
  #[4,]    4    2    5    5
```

Or if there are multiple datasets, we can place it in a list and work with `Reduce`

```
 Reduce(`+`, lapply(list(A,B), function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), 0)))
```

Another compact option would be to use `NAer` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
NAer(A)+NAer(B)
```

For multiple datasets

```
Reduce(`+`, lapply(list(A,B), NAer))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(324)
A <- matrix(sample(c(NA,1:5), 4*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=4)
set.seed(59)
B <- matrix(sample(c(NA,1:5), 4*4, replace=TRUE), ncol=4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `recode` from the `car` package

```
A <- matrix(c(1,NA,5,9,3,NA), 2)
B <- matrix(c(NA,10,3,NA,21,3), 2)

library(car)
Reduce("+", lapply(list(A, B), recode, "NA=0"))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    8   24
# [2,]   10    9    3
```